# Firestore Subcollection equivalent to mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently using the sub collection pattern of firestore which lets me save a collection inside a document.

That means that for my organization collection, I have organization documents and each document have sub collections like: projects,members, etc...
In that way I can always guarantee that for a specific document, I have all of its specific data scoped to it in a scalable way. This solves the embedding of data, let's say array, inside a document property that might get out of control.

Now, I did not find such a thing in mongodb. I did find that a Document can hold a subset of documents as an array but that's not exactly a sub collection.

A sub collection of a document will not return with the document unless is explicitly asked.

In mongodb subset, it's simply an array of documents inside a document which will come with the entire document.

Perhaps I'm wrong.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

Both Cloud Firestore and mongoDB are document-oriented database systems. However, a cool feature in Firestore is the possibility to create shallow queries to retrieve data at the document level without needing to retrieve the entire collection, or any nested subcollections. To get a similar behaviour in mongoDB you will have to generate your query specifically for this task.